# Rails asset path differs between asset_path and stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-sprockets

Using Sprockets in a Rails 6 development environment, `stylesheet_link_tag('mobile')` generates:

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" href=\"/assets/mobile.debug-2c11e2473c793c2475ab3559e38e0b0331956e570b884642ecbe1f21fa2467f1.css\" />
```

But `stylesheet_path('mobile')` generates:

```
"/assets/mobile-ea85a9ecd4c09607a4f2d7dbfeb5e145cdb4ce2033726041472418be82c104ae.css"
```

On the development server both of these asset paths render the same content.

But I need to cache the correct asset path in a service worker. How can I generate an asset path that matches that produced by the stylesheet_link_tag helper?

(I could avoid the stylesheet_link_tag helper, but presumably I'm missing something here)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because Sprockets separates out assets into individual files for inclusion when `config.assets.debug` is true - which it is by default in the development environment.

Sadly the option to toggle this flag off for an individual `stylesheet_link_tag` by setting the debug flag to false is broken - see this pull request:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/424

The workaround is to set `config.assets.debug` to false for the development environment, and to use `stylesheet_link_tag( 'mobile', debug: true )` if we need to debug a particular asset.